# File transfer in iPhone using XMPP chat

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am developing a chat application using XMPP framework. 
I can send and receive chat messages, and I want to transfer a file.

I used TURNSocket but it didn't work.

My code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSMutableArray *turnSockets=[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"venkat.varra@gmail.com/gmail.9D2001A1"];
    TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];
   [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
   [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}

- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket 
{
    NSData *dataF = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"orange" ofType:@"png"]];

    [socket writeData:dataF withTimeout:60.0f tag:0];
}

- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");
    [turnSockets removeObject:sender];          
}
```

When I run this program it always calles turnsocketDidFail method.

How can I achieve file transfers in a chat application using turn socket in iPhone?
can any one help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also getting the same.. How you solve it?

Comment: I'm also stuck at the same point...any solution for this?

Comment: Hey try to implement XEP-0096 http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileTransfer using XmppFrameWork in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114783/filetransfer-using-xmppframework-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a file then simply upload that file to your server using a web service and after the upload is complete, send the uploaded file URL to another user.
That user can now easily download the file from that specific URL.